# Image width in flex container

Tags: css, flexbox

An image with the same width and height doesn't always render as expected in a flex container with at least 1 other flex item. Its width seems to become smaller. Sometimes it renders fine, but often it doesn't (see image).

The weird thing is, is that if I remove the height declaration, the width always works well.

[image: Example of the problem]

Comment: Please don't post a screenshot of your code. Use [stack snippets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269753/9253414) instead.

Comment: @D.Pardal I can't, because the bug I'm talking about doesn't always occur. Hence the screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this same issue in my own code. In this case, I believe one of the issues is stemming from the image not being in its own div container like so:

```
<div class = "flex-container"> 
    <div class= "image"> 
        <img src = ""> 
    </div>
    <div class = "text">
        <p>
        </p> 
    </div> 
 </div>
```

Comment: If I add a div around it and set the height and width to 60px and then the height and width of the image inside to 100%, then the problem is the same.

Comment: does it help if you make the image size 100%?

Comment: That's what I tried. I make the image's width and height 100%, and the surrounding div's width and height is 60px. Then it's the same problem.

Comment: try adding this line to the .flex-container in the CSS: flex-direction: column;

Comment: I think it by default sets it to a row when it's just display flex and that might lead to the cramping of the image

Comment: and then I believe you can adjust how big each row in the div is by adding in the size in that selector in the CSS too